# Can I determine $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N}) [P(x) \implies (Q(x) \lor \lnot R(x))]$ without using a counter-example?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

Consider the following open propositions:

> $P(x) : 2 < x  \le 10 $
>
> $Q(x) : x$ is odd
>
> $R(x) : x$ is prime

Determine the truth value of

> $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N}) [P(x) \implies (Q(x) \lor \lnot R(x))]$

What I did was simplify it to

> $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N}) [\lnot P(x) \lor Q(x) \lor \lnot R(x)]$

So now all I have to do is show a number in $\mathbb{N}$ that turns $F_0$ for all three propositions. In this case, $4$ works, since

$\lnot P(4) \equiv F_0$ because $P(4) \equiv V_0$ since $2 < 4 \le 10$

$Q(4) \equiv F_0$ because $4$ is even

$R(4) \equiv F_0$ because $4$ is divisible by $2$

However, is it possible to determine the truth value of this **without using a counter-example**? I know it is easier to just show the counter-example - but I'm not sure how would I do it in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is actually true: it says that if $n$ is an integer between $3$ and $10$ inclusive, then $n$ is odd or $n$ is composite. Since every even integer greater than $2$ is composite, the statement is true.

You went astray in testing $4$: while $R(4)$ is indeed false, it’s $\neg R(n)$ that you have to falsify, not $R(n)$.

Comment: I think you want "every integer greater than $2$ is *odd* or composite"

Comment: @Ryan: I meant exactly what I wrote, which in any case is synonymous with your suggestion.

Comment: But what about $7$?

Comment: @Ryan: What about it? It’s not even, so my statement said nothing about it. Did you miss the word *even* in my statement?

Comment: Haha yes, that's weird I never noticed that until you just pointed it out!  My apologies.

Comment: @Ryan: No problem; I’ve been known to misread questions on occasion.

Comment: As you can see in my comment where I thought I quoted you, I left it out as well . . .  Poor reading on my part

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't have to use a counter-example here.

For many conditional statements you can assume the antecedent and then show that the consequent follows.  Here you can assume that x belongs {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.  Then, does it follow that x will either qualify as odd or not prime?  Well, if x belongs to {3, 5, 7, 9}, then x qualifies as odd.  So, x qualifies as odd or not prime.  If x belongs to {4, 6, 8, 10}, then x is not prime as each of the members of that set has a divisor other than 1 or itself.  So, x qualifies as odd or not prime in these cases also.  Since we've covered all cases, the conditional "if x belongs to {3, 4, ...}, then ..." holds as true.